# vb.net SQL date to time conversion issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, date

The error is: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Basically I'm trying to make it so that when someone clicks a location in a list box it increments the correct field in a Stats table by 1 to say that they clicked the location. I've been trying to solve this for a while now and can't get anywhere. My date is in date format, and so is the Date field in my Stats table. My code can be seen below.

```
    Dim Current As String
    Dim Check As String
    Dim objCmd2 As Object
    Dim iCount As Integer
    Dim tDate As Date

    Current = LocBox.SelectedItem

    Check = LocList.FindString(Current)

    If Check > -1 Then
        MsgBox("You have already selected this place to visit")
    Else
        LocList.Items.Add(Current)
        ObjDataReader.Close()
        tDate = Date.Today
        MessageBox.Show(tDate)
        tDate = tDate.ToString()
        objCmd2 = New SqlCommand("SELECT " & Replace(Current, " ", "_") & " FROM Stats WHERE Date = '" & tDate & "'", objConn)
        ObjDataReader = objCmd2.ExecuteReader
        If ObjDataReader.HasRows Then
            ObjDataReader.Read()
            If ObjDataReader(0) Is DBNull.Value Then
                iCount = 0
            Else
                iCount = ObjDataReader(0)
            End If
        Else
            iCount = 0
        End If
        objCmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Stats(Date," & Replace(Current, " ", "_") & ") Values('" & tDate.Date & "'," & iCount & " )", objConn)
        ObjDataReader.Close()
        objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        objConn.Close()
```

Thanks in advance.

The issue comes in with the second SQL statement I think. I don't understand why adding a date into a date field would be an issue, I've tried adding it as a string which didn't work. Thanks for all the answers so far.

Comment: Use parameterised queries with parameters of the correct datatype. This is safer (SQL injection) and should resolve your issue.

Comment: What is the format of the datetime column in Sql Server?  Is it actually a date time?  Or is it something like varchar?  You should not be using strings when dealing with dates and times.  Use a DateTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess the issue is here: MessageBox.Show(tDate)

You need to convert the date to a string using tDate.ToString or whatever other method you want.

Are you getting compile errors?  I always code with Option Strict On, and your code would definitely bring up errors where you are not converting variables.

Answer (score 1):

As Martin points out this is probably the best choice:

```
int colnum = ConvertColumnNameToNumber(Current)
objCmd2 = New SqlCommand("SELECT "+colnum.ToString()+" FROM Stats WHERE [Date] = @inDate", objConn)
objCmd2.Parameters.Add("@inDate",SqlDbType.DateTime).value = tDate
```

Not tested or compiled might have typos.

Note the use of colnum above.  Because you can't use parameters for column names you have to use the column number.  If you have code that returns an integer as a return value you can protect against injection (it can only a number).

Comment: Why would that help? If the OP gets the message `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.` adding an explicit cast would still give them the same error. The string is clearly not in an acceptable format for SQL Server.

Comment: I believe cast returns null when it fails -- so it would not throw an error.

Comment: @Hogan - You believe entirely incorrectly then - and even if it did (which it doesn't) wouldn't the more correct thing to do be to fix the string format so that SQL Server understood it? (though the only really correct answer here is to use parameters)

Comment: @Martin -- good -- then please let me know an SQL statement that can handle illegal date formats and not fail.

Comment: @Hogan - Why would you even pass illegal date formats into SQL Server? You would format the date as ISO `yyyymmdd` to avoid this kind of issue though the only answer I would upvote here would be one showing how to use parameters.

Comment: @Martin -- Ok, wrote it, do I have typos?

Comment: Only typo I got was an extra bracket on the second line. Will try this, though I still think this first sql statement isn't the issue.

Comment: @Coolmurr - You should be able to use an analogous technique for the second query but pass in an `int` parameter for `iCount` as well on that one. `SELECT @Current ` won't work though as column names can't be parameterised.

Comment: @Coolmurr, @Martin -- I changed it to show the safe way to "not" parameterize a column name.  You can't use a string returned from the broswer but if you have a helper function that only returns and integer you are safe.

Answer (score 0):

I may be off base but you have tDate as a Date variable type and then your trying to send it a string, you can just use tDate.ToString() in your SqlCommand lines and not convert it first.

Answer (score 0):

Try Removing the apostrophes from around tdate so that it is...

```
objCmd2 = New SqlCommand("SELECT " & Replace(Current, " ", "_") & " FROM Stats WHERE Date = " & tDate, objConn)
```

and

```
objCmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Stats(Date," & Replace(Current, " ", "_") & ") Values(" & tDate.Date & "," & iCount & " )", objConn)
```